# HCK USB-IF Certification - No Passing USB20CV CH9 Test

Tags: windows, usb, driver, device-driver, driver-signing

I'm trying to certify a USB device and I pass every test but the USB-IF Certification Validation Test(Device)

I run the "USB 3 Gen X CV" and pass the 2.0, chapter 9 tests.  I then take the 3 files and move them to c:/usblogs (I'm using the client machine to run USB-IF tests).

But I recieved the "No Passing USB30CV CH9 Test for USB2.0 logs found for the specified device" message.

Then I found this post about renaming the files: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3227a1b0-069e-4593-9861-18d66f9dca72/usbif-test-results-log-file-format?forum=whck#e134fca5-e164-4d8c-8875-2dc2d66b9232

But that didn't work.  I also have a previous submission to look thru and noticed that it used to produce a .log file instead of .bak.  I tried just renaming but no luck.

I tried finding older versions of USB30CV but to no avail.

I also tried to run USBIFValidation.exe manually and see what fails but it exceptions for not finding "Vex.Logger.Interop".

Using Windows 8.1 64

Could really use the help!  Not sure what else to try.  Sorry, not enough rep to post my pictures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming as mentioned in the link does work but you need to make sure you get every reference to "USB 2".
So just rename the files, and all occurrences of "USB 2" in the .html file with "USB 2.0" and you should be good to go.

Comment: It seems as though the logs have changed yet again - I'm running version 2.6 of the USB30CV tool, and even when renaming all the `USB 2` to `USB 2.0` it's still not happy. It appears that the three files have turned in to two files and a directory of about 16 files. HCK doesn't like this either.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem for actual USB3CV_x64 and HCK. No support from Microsoft. After all I found out that problem is single apostrophe ('). Application usbifvalidation.exe check only meta data of html log (no other files needed). So replace all single apostrophes (') by (") in all  items and replace USB 2 by USB 2.0.

Example:

```
<META name="Suite-Name" content="Chapter 9 Tests [USB 2.0 devices].cvtests" />
<META name="Suite-Result" content="PASS" />
...
```